# Add number of line and a specific character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

i have a file.txt who contains lines like this :

```
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
TEST4
```

i want to have an output like this, with number of line with > in the beginning, then jump the line :

```
>1
TEST1
>2
TEST2
>3
TEST3
>4
TEST4
```

I tried the following command

```
awk '{print ">"};{ print NR,$0};' file.txt > file2.txt
```

But it gives me a bad result

```
>
1 TEST1
>
2 TEST2
>
3 TEST3
>
4 TEST4
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{ print ">"NR }1' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it works
Can you explain me the 1 after braces? because when i try with 2, 3, 4 or 5 it doesn't change anything

Comment: `awk's` default action is printing. `1` is an idiomatic way of saying that print the line.

Comment: The `1` (or `2`, or any truthy value) causes the following action to be taken unconditionally on the current line. Since there is no action, the default (print the line) is used.

Comment: @chepner right, I should have added any value other than `0` which signifies true.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 'print ">$.\n"' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `awk` is a little bit too strong for this. A pure `bash` version:

```
while read; do echo -e ">$((++i))\n$REPLY"; done<<XXX
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
TEST4
XXX
```

Output

```
>1
TEST1
>2
TEST2
>3
TEST3
>4
TEST4
```

Without the here-is-the-document stuff:

```
while read; do echo -e ">$((++i))\n$REPLY"; done<file.txt
```

Comment: interesting ! how can i put my file.txt in this ? 
can we do this without done<<XXX ? thx

Comment: @Adeel: You just have to replace the here-is-the-document part with `<file.txt`.

Comment: @Adeel: U R welcome! It could be less cryptic using: `while read x; do echo -e ">$((++i))\n$x"; done`